# SPA with ui Router Angular JS too many files

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

This is a conceptual doubt.

Recently I began develop a SPA (Single Page Application) using the partial rendering with ui Router (more information about ui router [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)).

But as the application becomes more complex, with more features and information I saw that for a SPA I have only one page, called whatever you want (index.html, base.html, layout.html, etc...) and in this page I import many javascript files.

Foi então que conforme a aplicação foi crescendo e ficando com mais funcionalidades e mais informações eu vi que para o conceito de SPA eu tinha uma única página podem chamar como quiser (index.html, layout.html, base.html, etc...) e nela eu importo dezenas de arquivos javascript, pois eles representam minha aplicação.

Was a SPA just some parts of the page will be renderized by the routes request. Because of this I need all components, controllers, directives and etc right off the bat, when the aplication starts.

This cause a cascade effect, because, as the application grows I need to import more files, and this files becomes more heavy to load.

Example:

I have de following files

```
app.js
routes.js
controllers/
|--------- users/
|--------------- UserControler.js
|--------------- UserProfileController.js
|--------- appointments/
|--------------- AppointmentsControler.js
|--------- tasks/
|--------------- TasksControler.js
|--------------- TasksManagerController.js
directives/
|--------- basic/
|--------------- DropdownPattern.js
|--------- users/
|--------------- RefreshForm.js
services/
|--------- users/
|--------------- UsersServices.js
```

And so on....

So in my main page I have.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src"libs/angularjs.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src"libs/ui-router.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src"libs/angular-resource.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src"app.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src"routes.js">

<!-- Controllers import -->
<script type="text/javascript" src"controllers/users/UserControler.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src"controllers/users/UserProfileController.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src"controllers/appointments/AppointmentsControler.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src"controllers/tasks/TasksControler.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src"controllers/tasks/TasksManagerController.js">

<!-- Directives import -->
<script type="text/javascript" src"directives/basic/DropdownPattern.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src"directives/users/RefreshForm.js">

<!-- Services import -->
<script type="text/javascript" src"services/users/UsersServices.js">
```

This is the right pattern/architecture for a SAP application? Exist another way to use routes maybe with the server for load the files as they are requested?

I imagine in the final application the first load when **everything** will load to be in browser cache will be a long, long load.

Comment: Look into Webpack or JSPM!

Comment: Here is an example with Gulp, no webpack or JSPM: https://github.com/clinington/shopping

Comment: Here is an [example](https://github.com/no1melman/Typescript-Webpack/tree/master/Typescripting.Client) of AngularJs + Typescript + Webpack. I know you're using JavaScript, but that is only a minor (small small small) change in the webpack config.

Comment: Hi @CallumLinington thank you for your suggest. I'll be looking the links. Using Gulp as you mentioned, when I deploy it on server. How it you works?

Comment: So in the gulp script you can check whether you fire the script with `--production` or not and inside the script you can make changes depending on this environment variable.[resource](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/gulp/minify-only-production)